# AH01328: Line too long + AH01102: error reading status line from remote server + AH00898: Error reading from remote server

Tags: php, mysql

hope you are safe and well.
In server log files Im getting these 3 errors:

```
[substitute:error] 
AH01328: Line too long, URI /api/api_orol.php/, referer (URL)

[proxy_http:error] 
AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:81, referer (URL)

[proxy:error] 
AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /api/api_orol.php/, referer (URL)
```

At first I thought that it will be connected to shared hosting PHP or APACHE settings, but after some googling I think it might be connected to bad quality of PHP code (below)
In some discussion they recommend to change GET method to POST. Could this be the problem? What is best way to change GET to POST?

api_orol.php file as mentioned in error server log:

```
<?php
$username="username";
$db="database";
$password='password;
$socket='socket number';
$host="host";


// get the HTTP method, path and body of the request
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

// connect to the mysql database
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db, $socket);
if (!$link) {
    die("{'error': {'title': 'Connection failed', 'detail':'" . mysqli_connect_error() . "'}}");
}
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');

// retrieve the table and key from the path
$table = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
$key = array_shift($request)+0;

// escape the columns and values from the input object
$columns = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_keys($input));
$values = array_map(function ($value) use ($link) {
    if ($value===null) return null;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link,(string)$value);
}, array_values($input));

// build the SET part of the SQL command
$set = '';
for ($i=0;$i<count($columns);$i++) {
    $set.=($i>0?',':'').'`'.$columns[$i].'`=';
    $set.=($values[$i]===null?'NULL':'"'.$values[$i].'"');
}

// create SQL based on HTTP method
switch ($method) {
  case 'GET':
    $sql = "select * from `$table`".($key?" WHERE `key`=$key":''); break;
  case 'PUT':
    $sql = "update `$table` set $set where `key`=$key"; break;
  case 'POST':
    $sql = "insert into `$table` set $set"; break;
  case 'DELETE':
    $sql = "delete from `$table` where `key`=$key"; break;
}

// excecute SQL statement
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

// die if SQL statement failed
if (!$result) {
  http_response_code(404);
  //die("{'error': {'title': 'Could not query', 'detail':'" . mysqli_error($link) . "'}}");
  echo '{"error":"' . mysqli_error($link) . '"}';
  die('');
}

// print results, insert id or affected row count
if ($method == 'GET') {
    if (!$key) echo '{"data": [';
    for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++) {
        echo ($i>0?',':'').json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
    if (!$key) echo ']}';
} elseif ($method == 'POST') {
    echo '{ "id":' . mysqli_insert_id($link) . '}';
} else {
    echo '{"test":1}';
}

// close mysql connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: This `file_get_contents('php://input')` suggests that it actually expects a POST request since GET requests don't contain a body. POST is always a better choice if it's sending data to the server to be stored. GET request are, as the name implies, for getting data. Can't you ask the person who wrote that PHP code how you should use it?

Comment: Are you manually preparing JSON? Is there a reason for this?